# Compact subclasses of $R^\mathbb{N}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, measure-theory, probability-theory

I am following this source: http://www.hss.caltech.edu/~kcb/Notes/Kolmogorov.pdf and agree with everything done in sections 1-3.

In section 4, I cannot fill in the detail for for Lemma 4, because I cannot deal with the finite unions.

Also, I tried to apply the result of section 3 directly to $R^\mathbb{N}$ but I could not find a compact class with the desired property.  I tried the set of finite-dimensional cylinders where the nontrivial section is compact, but I just can't see that this is a compact class. (I.e. sets of the form $K \times R \times R...$ where $K$ is a compact subset of some $R^n$.)

For some sort of self-containedness, a compact class is one where every sequence in the class has the property that all finite intersections being nonempty implies the whole intersection of the sequence is nonempty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand{\ms}{\mathscr}$Let $\ms C$ be a compact class. Let $$\ms C_u=\left\{\bigcup\ms F:\ms F\subseteq\ms C\text{ is finite}\right\}\;,$$ and suppose that $\{F_n:n\in\Bbb N\}\subseteq\ms C_u$ is centred (i.e., finite intersections are non-empty); we want to show that $\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb N}F_n\ne\varnothing$.

Let $\displaystyle\Phi=\prod_{n\in\Bbb N}\ms F_n$; a point $\varphi\in\Phi$ is a sequence $\varphi=\langle C_n^\varphi:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ such that $C_n^\varphi\in\ms F_n$ for each $n\in\Bbb N$. Then

$$\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb N}F_n=\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb N}\bigcup\ms F_n=\bigcup_{\varphi\in\Phi}\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb N}C_n^\varphi\;.$$

(This is just distributivity of intersection over union, though you may have to think about it a bit if you’ve not seen an instance of the infinite distributive law before.)

Thus, $\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb N}F_n\ne\varnothing$ iff there is a $\varphi\in\Phi$ such that $\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb N}C_n^\varphi\ne\varnothing$. The existence of such a $\varphi$ will follow from [König’s lemma](http://caicedoteaching.wordpress.com/2009/08/24/502-konigs-lemma/) after we build a suitable tree.

For each $n\in\Bbb N$ and $\varphi\in\Phi$ let $\varphi_n=\varphi\upharpoonright\{k\in\Bbb N:k<n\}$. Viewed as a set of ordered pairs, $\varphi=\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}\varphi_n$; if $\varphi$ is viewed as a sequence, $\varphi_n$ is its initial segment of length $n$. Note that $\varphi_n\subsetneqq\varphi_{n+1}$ for each $\varphi\in\Phi$ and $n\in\Bbb N$. Let $$T=\left\{\varphi_n:\varphi\in\Phi,~n\in\Bbb N,\text{ and }\bigcap_{k<n}C_k^\varphi\ne\varnothing\right\}\;;$$

$\langle T,\subseteq\rangle$ is a tree. The root of $T$ is $\varnothing=\varphi_0$ for all $\varphi\in\Phi$. The predecessors of $\varphi^n\in T$ are the $\varphi^k$ with $k<n$. Each $\varphi_n\in T$ has at most $|\ms F_{n+1}|$ children, so $T$ is finitely branching. Finally, for each $n\in\Bbb N$ we know that $\bigcap_{k\le n}F_k\ne\varnothing$, so there must be some $\varphi^n\in T$, and $T$ is therefore infinite. By König’s lemma there must be a $\varphi\in\Phi$ such that $\varphi^n\in T$ for all $n\in\Bbb N$, and therefore

$$\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb N}F_n\supseteq\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb N}C_n^\varphi\ne\varnothing\;,$$

since $\ms C$ is a compact class.

Closing $\ms C_u$ under countable intersections shouldn’t be a problem.

Comment: @amWhy: Thanks! That one was fun.